# Failed to start signInAsync as concurrent GoogleSignIn task

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, expo

I have an app that I'm using to sign in into google with the expo-google-sign-in library. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to start signInAsync as a concurrent GoogleSignIn task is already running
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2864:45
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:100167:40
invokeAuthMethod$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:157126:80
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29230:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29403:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29230:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29303:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:29313:21
tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:4064:16
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:4165:27
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:31253:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:31292:17
callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:31509:33
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3358:35
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3144:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3341:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3143:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Pressable, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  // useEffect(async function () {
  //     try {
  //       console.log("running initAsync")
  //       await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
  //         // You may ommit the clientId when the firebase `googleServicesFile` is configured
  //         clientId: '435403173197-1ofadf8gflla92ibd6ibveb4tvv1vice.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  //         // Provide other custom options...
  //       });
  //     } catch ({ message }) {
  //       alert('GoogleSignIn.initAsync(): ' + message);
  //     }
  // }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={require(
      "../assets/images/happy-tiny-people-listening-spiritual-music/5870.jpg")}
      style={styles.background}>

<Pressable onPress= {() => {
      console.log("running sign in async");
      GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
    }}
    style={({ pressed }) => [{
            backgroundColor: pressed ? 'white' : '#03befc'
        },
    styles.google]}>
   <Image source={require("../assets/google_signin.png")} style={styles.googleImage}/>
   <Text style={styles.googleText}>Sign In With Google</Text>
   </Pressable>
    </ImageBackground>

        </View>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this error? I expect there to be no error and that the google sign in to happen. The error occurs when the perusable is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const signInAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
      const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
      if (type === 'success') {
       // success
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert('login: Error:' + message);
    }
};

<Pressable onPress= {() => { signInAsync() }
```

More detail here [sdk/google-sign-in/](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/)

Comment: This gives the error: Missing GogleService-info.plist

Comment: You have to add `GogleService-info.plist` in you code which extract you from configurating google app on firebase. Go to this link and setup app and get GogleService-info.plisthttps://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/?redirected